# Save data about signal in file?

Tags: c, linux, file, signals

I am trying to save certain information about the signal in a file, e.g. time it was caught, etc, in the signal handler.

```
void sig_handler(int signo){
   curr_signal = time(NULL);
   receivedtime[z] = curr_signal;
   signumber = signo;

   diff = curr_signal - receivedtime[z-1];
   z++;
   write(f, &diff, sizeof(diff));
}
```

I have updated my program to write inside the file (f). My problem is that nothing is being written inside the file.The file is being created.

Comment: Have you tried compile and lunch your snippet?

Comment: @Gluttton It doesn't write down anything in my file

Comment: Can you add code to check the return value of `write` ?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about the calls from inside your signal handler.

From `man 7 signal`:

```
Async-signal-safe functions
   A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing  else‐
   where  may  be  interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution of
   the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".   If  a  signal
   interrupts  the  execution  of  an  unsafe function, and handler either
   calls an unsafe function [...],
   then the behavior of the program is undefined.
```

And follows a list of the functions that are async-signal-safe.

Your signal handler calls:

- `time()`: ok, it is async-signal-safe
- `fprintf()`: nope, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer tells you why it doesn't work: you call signal-unsafe functions in your signal handler. I want to add what to do instead: it's best practice to do *as little as possible* inside the handler and instead inform your "normal" code about the signal. This can be done using a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable. Just update your data structures and set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` to `1`. In your main code, check that variable periodically, and if it is set, do the desired output and set it back to `0`.